# Filter ng-repeat more times

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating an application to manage restaurant orders.

I create the menu from $http so I've this list:

```
<div class="row vertical" style="background-image: url(/gest/images/etichette/ANTIPASTI.png);border-color: #0CF">
          <div class="card piatti col s2" ng-repeat="anti in antis | filter:{tipo:'ANTIPASTI'}">
<div class="card-content"> <span class="card-title truncate red darken-3">{{anti.piatto}}</span> </div>
            <div class="card-action"> <a href="#" ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" ng-click="insert(n,com,anti.id,anti.tipo,marcia)">{{n}}</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The div with class "row vertical" contain one time starters, then pasta, then beef ecc.
So I use ng-repeat each time, and filter by tipo.
My question is: is there any way to make ng-repeat only one time to show all menu (orderer before by starters, then pasta, beef ecc)?

I have this data (is a restaurant menu):

- `piatto`: name of the the dish
- `tipo`: category of the dish (like pasta, beef, fish, starters ecc)

I would show with only one repeat all the dishes ordered so:

```
starters, pasta, beef, fish, dessert etc.
```

And I would create each time a new row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you already have all your date on the `antis` and you just want to filter it by type **or** do you want to OrderIt by a certain type?

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87rqgqbp/7/) for example would order by name, but you can also provide an array with functions to retrieve each type in the way that you like, you can read about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

But basically you'd do

`anti in antis | orderBy:'+tipo'`

or

`anti in antis | orderBy: [ function(){}, function(){} ]`

EDIT:

As @yarons mentioned you can also chain strings to filter even further. I've updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87rqgqbp/15/) so now the filter would be `anti in antis | orderBy:['+tipo', '+piato']"` which indicates that first the `tipo` would be alphabetically ordered **ascending** (`+` indication) and after that the piato would also be alphabetically ascending.

If you'd want to define a different order than the alphabetical one I think you can use a sort of ENUM for the `tipo` as in:

```
var tipoENUM = {};
tipoENUM['ANIPASTI'] = 0;
tipoENUM['PASTA'] = 1;
tipoENUM['PIZZA'] = 2;
tipoENUM['BEEF'] = 3;
tipoENUM['DESERT'] = 4;
```

So that way you'd avoid using the string for the order, see following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87rqgqbp/18/) for the example.

EDIT 2:

Ok, so if you receive the data via the HTTP request it's better if you create a order function to help you, check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87rqgqbp/19/), like so:

```
// The enum would be defined as before but:
$scope.orderTipo = function (dish) {
    return tipoENUM[dish.tipo];
}
```

On the HTMl you'll do:

```
ng-repeat="anti in antis | orderBy:[orderTipo, '+piato']"
```

Comment: you can use an array of strings as well `ng-repeat="anti in antis | orderBy:['+tipo', 'piato']"`

Comment: Your fiddle explain what I need, my problem is the use of enum with json data taken from $http!

Comment: @DigitalXP Ok, got what you mean, just updated the answer to fit that need, you'd basically create a function to order it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok your example is perfect but I would repeat each time the "tipo" and then the relative "piato" in a list....something like this:

ANTIPASTI
- bruschetta
- suppli
- fritto

PRIMI
- caqrbonara
- amatriciana

etc.

Is it possible?